# Simple game of lotto in Python v 2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the second version of my lotto game, based on [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169044/a-simple-lotto-game-in-python) thread before. I hope I used all the tips I was given, also I fixed it using only functions as promised.

**Game rules**

> Each player is given 15 numbers, in increasing order. This is why I
>   use `sorted()` on the lists of player and computer. Also there is a
>   common list with numbers in it from 1 to 90.
>
> A random number is picked and removed from this list and printed to
>   players. The player who has this number in his card crosses it out or
>   skips its turn. This continues until either player or computer crosses
>   out all his numbers, or for some strange reason they are out of
>   numbers. I think in other parts of the world it is also called BINGO
>   but I might be wrong.

```
import random
import os

number_pool = list(range(1, 11))  # 1 , 101
player_card = sorted(random.sample(number_pool, 3))  # 15
computer_card = sorted(random.sample(number_pool, 3))  # 15


def random_choice(num_pool):
    choice = random.choice(num_pool)
    num_pool.remove(choice)
    # print("Current lotto: " + str(choice))
    return choice


def game_status_check():
    if len(player_card) == 0 or len(computer_card) == 0:
        print("Game over !")
        return True
    else:
        return False


def printout_cards():
    print("######################################\n")
    print("Player card: " + str(player_card))
    print("\n######################################\n")
    print("Computer card: " + str(computer_card))


def end_game():
    answer = input("Do you want to restart the game [y or n] ?: ")
    if answer == "y":
        main()
    elif answer == "n":
        print("Thank you for playing ! ")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Enter y or n !")


def main():
    while not game_status_check():
        printout_cards()
        random_number = random_choice(number_pool)
        print("Random lotto is: {}".format(random_number))
        answer = input("Do you want to cross out number [y or n]: ")
        if answer == "y":
            player_card.remove(random_number)
            if random_number in computer_card:
                computer_card.remove(random_number)
        elif answer == "n":
            if random_number in player_card:
                print("The number was in your card, you missed it and lost !")
                end_game()
            elif random_number in computer_card:
                computer_card.remove(random_number)
        os.system("cls")
        game_status_check()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: also i shortened the numbers to be able to test more hastily

Answer (score 1):

For a basic program like this, everything is more or less okay. Here are some nits:

1. `game_status_check()` should only do checking. Put the `print("Game over !")` in your main function.

   ```
   def game_status_check():
       return len(player_card) == 0 or len(computer_card) == 0
   ```

   This also removes the need for you to do:

   ```
   while not game_status_check():
       ...
       game_status_check()
   ```
2. What happens if a player doesn't remove a card that was in their set of player cards, and then enters an answer that's not `y` or `n`? Your `end_game()` function has a handler for that, but doesn't prompt the user again for input. Suggestion:

   ```
   def end_game():
       answer = input("Do you want to restart the game [y or n] ?: ")
       while answer != "y" and answer != "n":
           answer = input("Do you want to restart the game [y or n] ?: ")
       if answer == "y":
           main()
       else:
           print("Thank you for playing ! ")
           exit()
   ```
3. This change is optional and is purely my opinion to make the output look better.

   ```
   def printout_cards():
       print("######################################\n")
       print("Player card: {}".format(" ".join(player_card)))
       print("\n######################################\n")
       print("Computer card: {}".format(" ".join(computer_card)))
   ```
4. I would suggest not naming a function `random_choice()` for readability. It can easily be confused with `random.choice()`.

Comment: thnaks alot for the review and interesting tips m8 !